# How can I resize, then render to a canvas with react-redux

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, reactjs, react-redux

I'm writing a react-redux app and can't figure out how to render to a canvas once it has been resized.

Basically, I have two sliders which, when changed, update the width and the height of my canvas. In my reducer, I can render to the canvas during this state update. However, once the canvas receives its new dimensions, it is cleared.

So, what I'm trying to do is update the state, then once React has rendered the newly resized canvas, I need to render to it (preferably in the same reducer holding the canvas dimensions).

Currently, I'm trying to do this with redux-thunk like this:

```
export const setWidthAndRender = (width) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(setWidth(width));

  setTimeout(dispatch(renderToCanvas), 10);
};
```

This doesn't work, though. I'd like to somehow dispatch renderToCanvas once I'm sure it has been rendered by React.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add to your canvas state a new property, for example, "newWidth" which will be true if you have to re-render your canvas and false if you dont have to.

Your function setWidth should change newWidth to true so the component will know that your width has changed in the next call to "componentDidUpdate".

componentDidUpdate() should look like this

```
componentDidUpdate(){
        let {newWidth} = this.props.canvasProps
        let {renderToCanvas} = this.props.actions;

        if(newWidth === true){
            renderToCanvas(); // Set newWidth to false inside renderToCanvas()
        }
    }
```

This way should work :P